# Why does my subdomain only work in Chrome?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-chrome, browser, subdomain

I've added a Virtual Host to my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/website/sub"
    ServerName sub.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have two .htaccess files (for the moment identical), one for localhost and one for sub.localhost

**website/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**website/sub/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now if I open `http://sub.localhost` in my Chrome it works as expected. However when I open it in Safari, Firefox or Opera I get a message basically saying that the server was not found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Chrome will make some magic and resolve all subdomain of localhost to 127.0.0.1.

You have to add `127.0.0.1   sub.localhost` to your host file

- Linux: /etc/hosts
- OSX: /private/etc/hosts
- Windows: %windows%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: Are you sure your path for MAC is correct? Isn't it rather `/private/etc/hosts`? What should the line in the hosts file exactly look like? Could you clarify?